# Combining data frames as set output in a list

Tags: r, data.table

I am trying to combine a bunch of data.frames (which all have exactly the same structure) using the rbindlist call.

All of my data.frames have the same naming convention "WUP_" followed by a country name. As such I am using the call below to first make a list of all of the data.frames in my environment which begin with "WUP" and then applying rbindlistas follows:

```
wlist <- rbindlist(list(ls(pattern="WUP*")))
```

However, I am getting the following error:

```
Error in rbindlist(list(ls(pattern = "WUP*"))) : 
  Item 1 of list input is not a data.frame, data.table or list
```

the list itself looks like this - so I this part is working:

```
list(c("WUP_Angola", "WUP_Botswana", "WUP_Burundi", "WUP_Comoros", 
"WUP_Eritrea", "WUP_Ethiopia", "WUP_Kenya", "WUP_Lesotho", "WUP_Madagascar", 
"WUP_Malawi", "WUP_Mayotte", "WUP_Mozambique", "WUP_Namibia", 
"WUP_Rwanda", "WUP_Seychelles", "WUP_Somalia", "WUP_South.Africa", 
"WUP_South.Sudan", "WUP_Swaziland", "WUP_Uganda", "WUP_United.Republic.of.Tanzania", 
"WUP_Zambia", "WUP_Zimbabwe"))
```

And I've checked the structure of the objects in the environment and they are data.frames e.g.

```
str(WUP_Angola)
'data.frame':   48 obs. of  23 variables:
 $ Location: Factor w/ 1 level "Angola": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ Year    : int  1980 1985 1990 1995 2000 2005 2010 2015 1980 1985 ...
 $ Sex     : Factor w/ 2 levels "Female","Male": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ Area    : Factor w/ 3 levels "Rural","Total",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 ...
 $ X.0.4.  : int  567 628 654 679 707 757 795 788 746 896 ...
 $ X.5.9.  : int  426 476 496 526 550 589 637 678 563 682 ...
 $ X.10.14.: int  345 366 378 392 409 452 482 523 472 552 ...
 $ X.15.19.: int  295 314 312 327 340 381 403 432 403 472 ...
 $ X.20.24.: int  248 271 272 275 291 321 345 367 336 401 ...
 $ X.25.29.: int  210 231 239 247 253 275 296 321 277 332 ...
 $ X.30.34.: int  163 192 201 212 218 225 244 266 213 272 ...
 $ X.35.39.: int  143 149 167 178 188 191 199 219 184 208 ...
 $ X.40.44.: int  125 131 131 150 161 165 171 180 158 179 ...
 $ X.45.49.: int  107 114 114 117 135 138 146 152 134 153 ...
 $ X.50.54.: int  90 96 97 99 101 111 118 126 113 128 ...
 $ X.55.59.: int  75 80 80 83 85 83 95 103 93 106 ...
 $ X.60.64.: int  58 62 63 65 67 66 68 79 73 83 ...
 $ X.65.69.: int  43 46 47 49 51 51 52 54 53 61 ...
 $ X.70.74.: int  28 30 31 33 35 34 36 38 34 40 ...
 $ X.75.79.: int  15 17 17 18 20 20 21 23 18 22 ...
 $ X.80..  : int  8 9 10 11 12 12 14 15 10 12 ...
 $ Total   : int  2945 3214 3311 3461 3622 3868 4123 4366 3881 4599 ...
 $ X       : logi  NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
```

Any idea what I might be doing wrong here?

Answer (score 4):

rbindlist takes a list of objects (e.g. data frames). You are giving a list of names.
rather try:

```
wlist <- rbindlist(mget(ls(pattern="WUP*")))
```

mget() will fetch the objects from the environment by name.

Corrected to implement comment.

Comment: hi Karl, thanks for the speedy response. This call didn't work, but if you remove the 'list' call it produces the desired result. Thanks for the tip on mget:)

Answer (score 1):

Karl's suggestion above was nearly there. Removing the 'list' call produces one data.frames which combines all others, as so:

```
wlist <- rbindlist((mget(ls(pattern="WUP*"))))
```